Querying json array in snowflake
I have the following Json structure in a column called IAEBREAKDOWNS
{
    "breakdownScope1and2": [
        {
            "breakdown": [
                {
                    "name": "DQS1",
                    "percent": 27,
                    "total": 1000
                },
                {
                    "name": "DQS2",
                    "percent": 27,
                    "total": 1000
                }
            ],
            "breakdownBy": "DQS",
            "viewBy": "Account",
            "weightedAverage": 1.22
        },
        {
            "breakdown": [
                {
                    "name": "2024",
                    "percent": 27,
                    "total": 1000
                },
                {
                    "name": "2023",
                    "percent": 27,
                    "total": 1000
                }
            ],
            "breakdownBy": "Year of Emission",
            "viewBy": "Account",
            "weightedAverage": null
        },
        {
            "breakdown": [
                {
                    "name": "2024",
                    "percent": 27,
                    "total": 1000
                },
                {
                    "name": "2023",
                    "percent": 27,
                    "total": 1000
                }
            ],
            "breakdownBy": "Year of Revenue",
            "viewBy": "Account",
            "weightedAverage": null
        }
    ]
}

I would like to select breakdown where breakdownBy = DQS and viewBy = "Account" and the table is ACCOUNTS_DATA
I have the following query but no results whats wrong
SELECT IAEBREAKDOWNS:breakdownScope1and2.breakdown 
FROM ACCOUNTS_DATA 
WHERE variationid = '063de708-a90a-42e2-849d-89d6d56cc00e' 
AND IAEBREAKDOWNS IS NOT NULL 
AND 
IAEBREAKDOWNS:breakdownScope1and2.breakdownBy = 'DQS' 
AND IAEBREAKDOWNS:breakdownScope1and2.viewBy = 'Account'


You can also use a FILTER instead of a flatten for this, now.  It's a fairly new function, but this is the example....stealing Simeon's CTE:
with data(iaebreakdowns, variationid) as (
select parse_json('{
    "breakdownScope1and2": [
        {
            "breakdown": [
                {
                    "name": "DQS1",
                    "percent": 27,
                    "total": 1000
                },
                {
                    "name": "DQS2",
                    "percent": 27,
                    "total": 1000
                }
            ],
            "breakdownBy": "DQS",
            "viewBy": "Account",
            "weightedAverage": 1.22
        },
        {
            "breakdown": [
                {
                    "name": "2024",
                    "percent": 27,
                    "total": 1000
                },
                {
                    "name": "2023",
                    "percent": 27,
                    "total": 1000
                }
            ],
            "breakdownBy": "Year of Emission",
            "viewBy": "Account",
            "weightedAverage": null
        },
        {
            "breakdown": [
                {
                    "name": "2024",
                    "percent": 27,
                    "total": 1000
                },
                {
                    "name": "2023",
                    "percent": 27,
                    "total": 1000
                }
            ],
            "breakdownBy": "Year of Revenue",
            "viewBy": "Account",
            "weightedAverage": null
        }
    ]
}'), '063de708-a90a-42e2-849d-89d6d56cc00e' 
)

Then, simply apply both of your filters in a nested fashion.  You result should be the array you were looking for:
select
    FILTER(FILTER(iaebreakdowns:breakdownScope1and2, i -> i:breakdownBy = 'DQS'), j -> j:viewBy = 'Account')[0]:breakdown
from data;


so lets start with the CTE to hold the DATA:
with data(iaebreakdowns, variationid) as (
select parse_json('{
    "breakdownScope1and2": [
        {
            "breakdown": [
                {
                    "name": "DQS1",
                    "percent": 27,
                    "total": 1000
                },
                {
                    "name": "DQS2",
                    "percent": 27,
                    "total": 1000
                }
            ],
            "breakdownBy": "DQS",
            "viewBy": "Account",
            "weightedAverage": 1.22
        },
        {
            "breakdown": [
                {
                    "name": "2024",
                    "percent": 27,
                    "total": 1000
                },
                {
                    "name": "2023",
                    "percent": 27,
                    "total": 1000
                }
            ],
            "breakdownBy": "Year of Emission",
            "viewBy": "Account",
            "weightedAverage": null
        },
        {
            "breakdown": [
                {
                    "name": "2024",
                    "percent": 27,
                    "total": 1000
                },
                {
                    "name": "2023",
                    "percent": 27,
                    "total": 1000
                }
            ],
            "breakdownBy": "Year of Revenue",
            "viewBy": "Account",
            "weightedAverage": null
        }
    ]
}'), '063de708-a90a-42e2-849d-89d6d56cc00e' 
)

and then show the data needs to be flattenered to access the array items of breakdownScope1and2
SELECT f.value:breakdown as breakdown
    ,f.value:breakdownBy
    ,f.value:viewBy
FROM data as d
,TABLE(FLATTEN(input=>d.iaebreakdowns:breakdownScope1and2)) as f
WHERE d.variationid = '063de708-a90a-42e2-849d-89d6d56cc00e' 


now pick the results as asked for with the correct filter:
SELECT f.value:breakdown as breakdown
FROM data as d
,TABLE(FLATTEN(input=>d.iaebreakdowns:breakdownScope1and2)) as f
WHERE d.variationid = '063de708-a90a-42e2-849d-89d6d56cc00e' 
    AND f.value:breakdownBy = 'DQS' 
    AND f.value:viewBy = 'Account'

the null check is not needed, because if the json is null, it will collaspe in the FLATTEN because the default beahvour is like a INNER JOIN.
